# Error Calling Intent

Tags: android

There is an error when I call the intent `startActivity (new Intent (this, Advogado1.class))`, How should I proceed to properly call this `Intent`

```
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("Atenção");
            alert.setMessage("Digite o Numero da OAB");

            // Set an EditText view to get user input
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {

                            int oab = Integer.parseInt(input.getText()
                                    .toString());
                            // Do something with value!

                            if (oab == 1) {

                                startActivity(new Intent(this, Advogado1.class));
                            }

                        }
                    });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            // Canceled.
                        }
                    });

            alert.show();
```

Comment: Post your logcat output please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to,

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Advogado1.class));
```

should not use 'this', it should use,

```
startActivity(new Intent(NameOfYourActivity.this, Advogado1.class));
```

because `this` refers to the anonymous class extending `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, and not your `Activity` class. The Intent needs the caller class to be an instance of Activity.